# Select range if - depending on a value of each cell of a range (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select whole rows of a range (C14:M34) if value = 1 in a column(F14:F34). Otherwise I want to select the same rows except a specific column(G).
I can do this if I have only a single row but how can I apply this for a range (multiple rows)?

Hereby my code (which is not working):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$13:$M$34").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"
    Dim d As Range
    For Each d In Range("F14:F34")
        If d.Value = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C14:M34").Select
        Else
        Application.Union(Range("C14:F34"), Range("H14:M34")).Select
        End If
        Selection.Copy
    Next d
```

Comment: Do you receive an error? What do you mean by "not working"? If you receive in error, this could be because a hidden row cannot be selected. You must iterate between the visible cells range...

Comment: I don't receive an error but it is just selecting the rows except column G - no matter what the value in column F

Comment: Do you run the code line by line, but at once and what you explained happens at the end? Please transform this line `ActiveSheet.Range("C14:M34").Select`  in  `ActiveSheet.Range("C14:M34").Select: Stop`...

Comment: I run this code at once and it is selecting all the rows in this range except column G even if I change the value(s) of column F to 1

Comment: **Did you try my suggestion**? It stops selecting according to its last check! If it is not 1, it selects as you instructed it...

Comment: thanks but your suggestion is only working if all values are 1 OR something else. If some cells have the value 1 and some not then it is skipping column G totally

Comment: What do you mean? Does the code select as you need, for that specific case of 1? I just wanted to show you that the code works as it should. YOU must know what to do (except copying the selection) when the code does as you 'instructed' it...

Comment: what I mean that my code is not working IF the value of some cells in column F is 1. It should select the whole rows where value = 1 and exclude column G where value <> 1. (if all cells in column F = 1 OR all cells <> 1 then it is working)

Comment: And doesn't it do that? Did you adapt the code according to my suggestion? If yes, what is selected on the code stops? If the value is 1, do you want to select everything (with column F:F included) or all rows containing 1?

Comment: I have changed my code following your suggestion and if value = 1 in one of the cells of column F then it is selecting only column F. What I want: if value = 1 in a cell of column F then select the whole row (C:M), but the same time skip column G in the rows where the value <> 1 and select the rest

Comment: Sorry... I cannot follow you. If the code is `ActiveSheet.Range("C14:M34").Select`, it MUST select the range "C14:M34"! I cannot understand what you want. Sorry... I will try the last shut: **What do you want  your code to select and in which conditions?**

Comment: I agree that it should select that range following to the code but if I copy the selection than only column F will be copied - really strange. I try to explain again what I want that the code does: select the whole row in range C14:M34 if value in column F = 1, otherwise (F <> 1) select the row without column G. This code should select the rows in range C14:M34 following to these conditions.

Comment: Let me rephrase: In case of 1 in column F:F, do you like to select **only that specific row** (inside of the range "C14:M34")? And also to select **only a row**, but excluding the cell of the column F:F from selection ,in case of something else in F:F?

Comment: Almost. So in case of 1 in column F:F, I would like to select only that specific row (inside of the range "C14:M34") and also to select the row in the same range but excluding the cell of the column G:G (not F:F) from selection in case of something else in F:F

Comment: I cannot help you. I cannot understand what you need... What does "also to select the row in the same range but excluding the cell of the column G:G (not F:F) from selection in case of something else in F:F" mean? Which such a row? The following one? Do you need to select two rows?

Comment: Lets say I have 3 rows in range "C14:M34" and only the second row has a value = 1 in column F. In this case I want to select the whole second row and the same time I want to select the first and the third row as well but excluding column G because they don't have a value = 1 in column F.

Comment: 1. You cannot have 3 rows in range "C14:M34". There are 20 rows independent of what we want.  2. Should I understand that finding one row having value 1 in column F:F, you want to select **all rows of the range "C14:M34"**, but, except the row with 1, **all the others to skip the cells in column G:G** and ends the code? Would that be correct? 3. If yes, is there **only one row containing 1 in column G:G**? If not, how the code has to proceed for the following occurrences?

Comment: More rows can contain 1 in column F:F. All rows with 1 in column F:F should be selected fully (C:M) and the same time all the other rows should be selected as well but skipping the cells in column G:G.

Comment: Finally, I could understand a simple issue... I will try to prepare a solution for your problem, as could understand it.

Comment: Please test my answer code and let me know if it works as you need, or what problem it creates, if any...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub testSelecting()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngSel As Range, i As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
    For i = 14 To 34
        If sh.Range("F" & i).Value = 1 Then
           If rngSel Is Nothing Then
              Set rngSel = sh.Range("C" & i & ":M" & i)
           Else
              Set rngSel = Union(rngSel, sh.Range("C" & i & ":M" & i))
           End If
        Else
            If rngSel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngSel = Union(sh.Range("C" & i & ":F" & i), sh.Range("H" & i & ":M" & i))
            Else
                Set rngSel = Union(rngSel, sh.Range("C" & i & ":F" & i), sh.Range("H" & i & ":M" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If rngSel.Cells.count > 1 Then rngSel.Select: Stop
    rngSel.Copy
End Sub
```

The code is not tested, because I do not have your file to do that. It is based only on logic. It stops after selection, in order to let you appreciate that the selected range is the one you need.

Please confirm that it works as you need, or what problem does it create, if any...

Comment: thanks a lot, it is working! the only issue I have that I want to copy the selected cells in Excel. If I don't have any cells containing 1 in column F:F than it is working perfect, but if I have some cells containing 1 than Excel doesn't let me to copy the selection. Another problem is that if all values = 1 in column F:F than somehow only the cells of column F:F will be copied, not the whole selection... I don't know if this has to do with VBA or Excel (or me)...

Comment: Excel does not allow copying of multiple selections, I know that. I just followed your code and I did not test it... But what do you want to do with your selected range? You can use a different approach. To enter all the range in an array and do whatever you need using it. The code selects the ranges as you wanted... Now, i have to live my office. When I will be at home, I will try to help you with the issue, but **only if you are able to ACCURATELY explain what is to be done with the range**. I am not sure I can be enough patient, to obtain a simple description of the need after other 2 hours

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help and sorry for not being clear! I need to copy all the selected data to another software which would save a lot of time. Do I understand you correctly that it would be possible to enter the selected data in an array and copy it to clipboard?

Comment: Not really... Can you 'communicate' with that 'another software' only by clipboard using?  Why it is necessary to have the gaps in that G:G column? Can you pass the information piece by piece? I mean, each range segment at a time? If I would needed to copy the information in the processed sheet to another one, there would be many ways of doing that. Not knowing your 'other software', I do not know how I would be able to help...

Comment: can't communicate with the software another way unfortunatelly. Gaps are needed because depending on the information of column F:F I need to copy the information of column G (or not) into the right field of the software. In case it is not necessary but I keep copying it messes up the fields.

Comment: Can't you send the ranges in small portions? I mean, for each row to copy all the range (C:M) if 1 in F:F column and C:F firstly, followed by H:M after... How the other software receives the clipboard content?